# Conditional summing across data frames in R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I am trying to replicate SUMIFS functionality in R.  I have two data frames.

Data Frame 1

```
allReported

ID       employeeGroup
1093     Bargaining Unit
1093     Management
1093     Non-Union
55       Bargaining Unit
55       Management
55       Non-Union
```

Data Frame 2

```
employeeCompSummary

ID       employeeGroup      statBenefits    regularWages
1093     Management         500.00          10000.00
1093     Management         200.00          60000.00
1093     Bargaining Unit    100.00          20000.00
1093     Bargaining Unit    150.00          30000.00
1093     Non-Union          500.00          60000.00
55       Bargaining Unit    750.00          65000.00
55       Bargaining Unit    500.00          75000.00
55       Management         250.00          45000.00
55       Management         850.00          90000.00
```

I am trying to sum statBenefits (and then later regular wages) to create a new table that would produce the following result:

```
ID       employeeGroup          statBenefits
1093     Bargaining Unit        250.00
1093     Management             700.00
1093     Non-Union              500.00
55       Bargaining Unit        1250.00
55       Management             1100.00
55       Non-Union              0.00
```

I have tried the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(allReported)[, list(total=sum(statbenefits)), list(employeeCompSummary, employeeGroup)]
```

and get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(allReported), , list(total = sum(statbenefits)),  :   column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type list. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

I also tried:

```
sumTest <- aggregate(allReported, by = list(employeeCompSummary), sum)
```

and got the following error:

```
**Error in aggregate.data.frame(allReported, by = list(employeeCompSummary),  :   arguments must have same length**
```

Any help anyone could provide would be very much appreciated.  I have looked at other questions that seem to deal with this but have not been able to find an answer that works.  I will be doing this task over multiple things so I was wondering if there is a straightforward technique anyone is aware of.  As always, thanks in advance to the wonderful community here on Stack Overflow.

Edit dput() of two example tables:

```
allReported <- structure(list(ID = c(1093, 1093, 1093, 1093, 1093, 55, 55, 55,55), employeeGroup = c("Management", "Management", "Bargaining Unit","Bargaining Unit", "Non-Union", "Bargaining Unit", "Bargaining Unit","Management", "Management"), statBenefits = c(500, 200, 100,150, 500, 750, 500, 250, 850), regularWages = c(10000, 60000,20000, 30000, 60000, 65000, 75000, 45000, 90000)), row.names = c(NA,-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

employeeCompSummary <- structure(list(ID = c(1093, 1093, 1093, 55, 55, 55), employeeGroup =c("Bargaining Unit","Management", "Non-Union", "Bargaining Unit", "Management", "Non-Union")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

 .
```

Comment: the data is confidential for work that is why I have listed the example tables above.

Comment: Can you provide those tables in `dput` format? That would make it easier for helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `magrittr` (for `%>%`) packages to do this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1093, 1093, 1093, 55, 55, 55), employeeGroup =c("Bargaining Unit","Management", "Non-Union", "Bargaining Unit", "Management", "Non-Union")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1093, 1093, 1093, 1093, 1093, 55, 55, 55,55), employeeGroup = c("Management", "Management", "Bargaining Unit","Bargaining Unit", "Non-Union", "Bargaining Unit", "Bargaining Unit","Management", "Management"), statBenefits = c(500, 200, 100,150, 500, 750, 500, 250, 850), regularWages = c(10000, 60000,20000, 30000, 60000, 65000, 75000, 45000, 90000)), row.names = c(NA,-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

result <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "employeeGroup")) %>%
  group_by(ID, employeeGroup) %>%
  summarize(
    statBenefits = sum(statBenefits, na.rm = T),
    regularWages = sum(regularWages, na.rm = T)
  )
result
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit based on your comment: One way to do it is to use data.table this way

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(structure(list(ID = c(1093, 1093, 1093, 1093, 1093, 55, 55, 55,55), 
               employeeGroup = c("Management", "Management", "Bargaining Unit","Bargaining Unit", "Non-Union", "Bargaining Unit", "Bargaining Unit","Management", "Management"), statBenefits = c(500, 200, 100,150, 500, 750, 500, 250, 850), regularWages = c(10000, 60000,20000, 30000, 60000, 65000, 75000, 45000, 90000)), 
          row.names = c(NA,-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), key = c("ID", "employeeGroup"))

dt2 <- data.table(structure(list(ID = c(1093, 1093, 1093, 55, 55, 55), employeeGroup =c("Bargaining Unit","Management", "Non-Union", "Bargaining Unit", "Management", "Non-Union")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), key = c("ID", "employeeGroup"))



dt1[dt2][, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("statBenefits", "regularWages"), by = c("ID", "employeeGroup")]
```

which gives

```
ID   employeeGroup statBenefits regularWages
1:   55 Bargaining Unit         1250       140000
2:   55      Management         1100       135000
3:   55       Non-Union           NA           NA
4: 1093 Bargaining Unit          250        50000
5: 1093      Management          700        70000
6: 1093       Non-Union          500        60000
```

You can later replace NA values with 0

Comment: That returns the following error:
    Error in dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("statBenefits", "regularWages"),  : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: `dt` is a function (try `?dt`) so when you try to subset it like it was a data.frame you get that error. If you rename your data with something doesn't clash with other R objects it should resolve that error

Comment: Another possible approach using `data.table`'s `.EACHI` is `employeeCompSummary[allReported, .(statBenefits=if (.N > 0) sum(statBenefits) else 0), 
    on=.(ID, employeeGroup), by=.EACHI]`

Comment: Nice answer. OP has now posted data which does not have keys. You might want to show how to assign keys and/or use `on=` so keys aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do...

```
library(data.table)

# don't use setDT, since who knows if it works on tibbeldies
ar = data.table(allReported)
ecs = data.table(employeeCompSummary)

ecs[, total := ar[.SD, on=.(ID, employeeGroup), sum(x.statBenefits), by=.EACHI][, V1]]

     ID   employeeGroup total
1: 1093 Bargaining Unit   250
2: 1093      Management   700
3: 1093       Non-Union   500
4:   55 Bargaining Unit  1250
5:   55      Management  1100
6:   55       Non-Union    NA
```

This code adds columns to `ecs` even though the OP requested a new table. The set of rows is identical between the new table and `ecs` so it seems like a waste of mental energy to carry around both of them. Dropping the columns later is straightforward.

If you want to know how this "update join" works, try working backwards...

```
ar[ecs, on=.(ID, employeeGroup), sum(x.statBenefits), by=.EACHI]

# or

ar[ecs, on=.(ID, employeeGroup)]
```

Note .SD == ecs in the original code. See `?.SD`.